# PyQt program starting to crash for no reason

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I developped a program in PyQt for Windows a few months ago that I turned into an executable with py2exe, and it's suddenly starting to crash for no obvious reason.

By crashing I mean that the program closes without any explanation. I can't reproduce the problem on demand because it never crashes at the same action.

Do someone has an idea of where I could look for an explanation ? How to debug something like this ?

Comment: It's most likely the converter's problem. I came across crashes even when i just test a few lines of pyqt code that was compile to exe file. However, everything is all right when i run the program through a interpreter. It's hard to debug exe file, so i suggest you using the latest and most stable converter.

Comment: try running it from the command line to see if you can get any errors

Answer (score 1):

The best thing to do is run your program in a debugger like gdb and get a stack trace. Sometimes this doesn't lead to an obvious solution, though.

Here's a collection of things to look out for that cause crashes with pyqt:
[What are good practices for avoiding crashes / hangs in PyQt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11945183/what-are-good-practices-for-avoiding-crashes-hangs-in-pyqt)

Comment: Thanks for the link, interesting read. I'll try to follow these advices.