# Core dump with PyQt4

Tags: ubuntu, pyqt4

I am starting with PyQt4 and am facing a coredump when using QGraphicsScene/View in the easiest of the examples:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

grview = QGraphicsView()
scene = QGraphicsScene()
grview.setScene(scene)

grview.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The program runs, but when closing it it gives tons of GTK errors (using Ubuntu) and finally the core dump (segmentation fault):

```
(python:2732): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_container_add: assertion `GTK_IS_CONTAINER (container)' failed

(python:2732): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_realize: assertion `GTK_WIDGET_ANCHORED (widget) || GTK_IS_INVISIBLE (widget)' failed

(python:2732): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_realize: assertion `GTK_WIDGET_ANCHORED (widget) || GTK_IS_INVISIBLE (widget)' failed

(python:2732): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_container_add: assertion `GTK_IS_CONTAINER (container)' failed

(python:2732): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_realize: assertion `GTK_WIDGET_ANCHORED (widget) || GTK_IS_INVISIBLE (widget)' failed

(python:2732): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_realize: assertion `GTK_WIDGET_ANCHORED (widget) || GTK_IS_INVISIBLE (widget)' failed

(python:2732): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_realize: assertion `GTK_WIDGET_ANCHORED (widget) || GTK_IS_INVISIBLE (widget)' failed

(python:2732): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_realize: assertion `GTK_WIDGET_ANCHORED (widget) || GTK_IS_INVISIBLE (widget)' failed

(python:2732): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_container_add: assertion `GTK_IS_CONTAINER (container)' failed

(python:2732): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_realize: assertion `GTK_WIDGET_ANCHORED (widget) || GTK_IS_INVISIBLE (widget)' failed

(python:2732): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_realize: assertion `GTK_WIDGET_ANCHORED (widget) || GTK_IS_INVISIBLE (widget)' failed

(python:2732): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_container_add: assertion `GTK_IS_CONTAINER (container)' failed

(python:2732): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_realize: assertion `GTK_WIDGET_ANCHORED (widget) || GTK_IS_INVISIBLE (widget)' failed

(python:2732): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_realize: assertion `GTK_WIDGET_ANCHORED (widget) || GTK_IS_INVISIBLE (widget)' failed

(python:2732): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_container_add: assertion `GTK_IS_CONTAINER (container)' failed

(python:2732): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_realize: assertion `GTK_WIDGET_ANCHORED (widget) || GTK_IS_INVISIBLE (widget)' failed

(python:2732): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_realize: assertion `GTK_WIDGET_ANCHORED (widget) || GTK_IS_INVISIBLE (widget)' failed

(python:2732): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_container_add: assertion `GTK_IS_CONTAINER (container)' failed

(python:2732): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_realize: assertion `GTK_WIDGET_ANCHORED (widget) || GTK_IS_INVISIBLE (widget)' failed

(python:2732): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_realize: assertion `GTK_WIDGET_ANCHORED (widget) || GTK_IS_INVISIBLE (widget)' failed

(python:2732): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_container_add: assertion `GTK_IS_CONTAINER (container)' failed

(python:2732): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_realize: assertion `GTK_WIDGET_ANCHORED (widget) || GTK_IS_INVISIBLE (widget)' failed

(python:2732): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_realize: assertion `GTK_WIDGET_ANCHORED (widget) || GTK_IS_INVISIBLE (widget)' failed

(python:2732): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_realize: assertion `GTK_WIDGET_ANCHORED (widget) || GTK_IS_INVISIBLE (widget)' failed

(python:2732): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_realize: assertion `GTK_WIDGET_ANCHORED (widget) || GTK_IS_INVISIBLE (widget)' failed

(python:2732): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_realize: assertion `GTK_WIDGET_ANCHORED (widget) || GTK_IS_INVISIBLE (widget)' failed

(python:2732): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_realize: assertion `GTK_WIDGET_ANCHORED (widget) || GTK_IS_INVISIBLE (widget)' failed

(python:2732): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_realize: assertion `GTK_WIDGET_ANCHORED (widget) || GTK_IS_INVISIBLE (widget)' failed

(python:2732): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_container_add: assertion `GTK_IS_CONTAINER (container)' failed

(python:2732): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_realize: assertion `GTK_WIDGET_ANCHORED (widget) || GTK_IS_INVISIBLE (widget)' failed

(python:2732): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_realize: assertion `GTK_WIDGET_ANCHORED (widget) || GTK_IS_INVISIBLE (widget)' failed

(python:2732): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_realize: assertion `GTK_WIDGET_ANCHORED (widget) || GTK_IS_INVISIBLE (widget)' failed

(python:2732): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_realize: assertion `GTK_WIDGET_ANCHORED (widget) || GTK_IS_INVISIBLE (widget)' failed

(python:2732): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_realize: assertion `GTK_WIDGET_ANCHORED (widget) || GTK_IS_INVISIBLE (widget)' failed

(python:2732): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_realize: assertion `GTK_WIDGET_ANCHORED (widget) || GTK_IS_INVISIBLE (widget)' failed

(python:2732): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_container_add: assertion `GTK_IS_CONTAINER (container)' failed

(python:2732): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_realize: assertion `GTK_WIDGET_ANCHORED (widget) || GTK_IS_INVISIBLE (widget)' failed

(python:2732): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_realize: assertion `GTK_WIDGET_ANCHORED (widget) || GTK_IS_INVISIBLE (widget)' failed

(python:2732): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_container_add: assertion `GTK_IS_CONTAINER (container)' failed

(python:2732): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_realize: assertion `GTK_WIDGET_ANCHORED (widget) || GTK_IS_INVISIBLE (widget)' failed

(python:2732): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_realize: assertion `GTK_WIDGET_ANCHORED (widget) || GTK_IS_INVISIBLE (widget)' failed

(python:2732): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_container_add: assertion `GTK_IS_CONTAINER (container)' failed

(python:2732): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_realize: assertion `GTK_WIDGET_ANCHORED (widget) || GTK_IS_INVISIBLE (widget)' failed

(python:2732): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_realize: assertion `GTK_WIDGET_ANCHORED (widget) || GTK_IS_INVISIBLE (widget)' failed

(python:2732): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_realize: assertion `GTK_WIDGET_ANCHORED (widget) || GTK_IS_INVISIBLE (widget)' failed

(python:2732): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_container_add: assertion `GTK_IS_CONTAINER (container)' failed

(python:2732): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_realize: assertion `GTK_WIDGET_ANCHORED (widget) || GTK_IS_INVISIBLE (widget)' failed

(python:2732): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_realize: assertion `GTK_WIDGET_ANCHORED (widget) || GTK_IS_INVISIBLE (widget)' failed

(python:2732): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_realize: assertion `GTK_WIDGET_ANCHORED (widget) || GTK_IS_INVISIBLE (widget)' failed

(python:2732): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_realize: assertion `GTK_WIDGET_ANCHORED (widget) || GTK_IS_INVISIBLE (widget)' failed

(python:2732): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_realize: assertion `GTK_WIDGET_ANCHORED (widget) || GTK_IS_INVISIBLE (widget)' failed

(python:2732): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_container_add: assertion `GTK_IS_CONTAINER (container)' failed

(python:2732): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_realize: assertion `GTK_WIDGET_ANCHORED (widget) || GTK_IS_INVISIBLE (widget)' failed

(python:2732): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_realize: assertion `GTK_WIDGET_ANCHORED (widget) || GTK_IS_INVISIBLE (widget)' failed

(python:2732): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_container_add: assertion `GTK_IS_CONTAINER (container)' failed

(python:2732): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_realize: assertion `GTK_WIDGET_ANCHORED (widget) || GTK_IS_INVISIBLE (widget)' failed

(python:2732): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_realize: assertion `GTK_WIDGET_ANCHORED (widget) || GTK_IS_INVISIBLE (widget)' failed

(python:2732): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_container_add: assertion `GTK_IS_CONTAINER (container)' failed

(python:2732): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_realize: assertion `GTK_WIDGET_ANCHORED (widget) || GTK_IS_INVISIBLE (widget)' failed

(python:2732): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_realize: assertion `GTK_WIDGET_ANCHORED (widget) || GTK_IS_INVISIBLE (widget)' failed

(python:2732): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_realize: assertion `GTK_WIDGET_ANCHORED (widget) || GTK_IS_INVISIBLE (widget)' failed

(python:2732): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_realize: assertion `GTK_WIDGET_ANCHORED (widget) || GTK_IS_INVISIBLE (widget)' failed

(python:2732): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_container_add: assertion `GTK_IS_CONTAINER (container)' failed

(python:2732): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_realize: assertion `GTK_WIDGET_ANCHORED (widget) || GTK_IS_INVISIBLE (widget)' failed

(python:2732): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_realize: assertion `GTK_WIDGET_ANCHORED (widget) || GTK_IS_INVISIBLE (widget)' failed

(python:2732): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_realize: assertion `GTK_WIDGET_ANCHORED (widget) || GTK_IS_INVISIBLE (widget)' failed

(python:2732): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_realize: assertion `GTK_WIDGET_ANCHORED (widget) || GTK_IS_INVISIBLE (widget)' failed

(python:2732): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_realize: assertion `GTK_WIDGET_ANCHORED (widget) || GTK_IS_INVISIBLE (widget)' failed

(python:2732): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_container_add: assertion `GTK_IS_CONTAINER (container)' failed

(python:2732): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_realize: assertion `GTK_WIDGET_ANCHORED (widget) || GTK_IS_INVISIBLE (widget)' failed

(python:2732): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_realize: assertion `GTK_WIDGET_ANCHORED (widget) || GTK_IS_INVISIBLE (widget)' failed

(python:2732): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_container_add: assertion `GTK_IS_CONTAINER (container)' failed

(python:2732): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_realize: assertion `GTK_WIDGET_ANCHORED (widget) || GTK_IS_INVISIBLE (widget)' failed

(python:2732): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_realize: assertion `GTK_WIDGET_ANCHORED (widget) || GTK_IS_INVISIBLE (widget)' failed

(python:2732): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_container_add: assertion `GTK_IS_CONTAINER (container)' failed

(python:2732): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_realize: assertion `GTK_WIDGET_ANCHORED (widget) || GTK_IS_INVISIBLE (widget)' failed

(python:2732): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_realize: assertion `GTK_WIDGET_ANCHORED (widget) || GTK_IS_INVISIBLE (widget)' failed

(python:2732): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_container_add: assertion `GTK_IS_CONTAINER (container)' failed

(python:2732): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_realize: assertion `GTK_WIDGET_ANCHORED (widget) || GTK_IS_INVISIBLE (widget)' failed

(python:2732): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_realize: assertion `GTK_WIDGET_ANCHORED (widget) || GTK_IS_INVISIBLE (widget)' failed

(python:2732): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_realize: assertion `GTK_WIDGET_ANCHORED (widget) || GTK_IS_INVISIBLE (widget)' failed

(python:2732): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_realize: assertion `GTK_WIDGET_ANCHORED (widget) || GTK_IS_INVISIBLE (widget)' failed

(python:2732): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_realize: assertion `GTK_WIDGET_ANCHORED (widget) || GTK_IS_INVISIBLE (widget)' failed

(python:2732): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_container_add: assertion `GTK_IS_CONTAINER (container)' failed

(python:2732): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_realize: assertion `GTK_WIDGET_ANCHORED (widget) || GTK_IS_INVISIBLE (widget)' failed

(python:2732): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_realize: assertion `GTK_WIDGET_ANCHORED (widget) || GTK_IS_INVISIBLE (widget)' failed

(python:2732): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_realize: assertion `GTK_WIDGET_ANCHORED (widget) || GTK_IS_INVISIBLE (widget)' failed

(python:2732): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_realize: assertion `GTK_WIDGET_ANCHORED (widget) || GTK_IS_INVISIBLE (widget)' failed

(python:2732): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_realize: assertion `GTK_WIDGET_ANCHORED (widget) || GTK_IS_INVISIBLE (widget)' failed

(python:2732): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_realize: assertion `GTK_WIDGET_ANCHORED (widget) || GTK_IS_INVISIBLE (widget)' failed

(python:2732): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_realize: assertion `GTK_WIDGET_ANCHORED (widget) || GTK_IS_INVISIBLE (widget)' failed

(python:2732): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_realize: assertion `GTK_WIDGET_ANCHORED (widget) || GTK_IS_INVISIBLE (widget)' failed

(python:2732): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_realize: assertion `GTK_WIDGET_ANCHORED (widget) || GTK_IS_INVISIBLE (widget)' failed

(python:2732): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_realize: assertion `GTK_WIDGET_ANCHORED (widget) || GTK_IS_INVISIBLE (widget)' failed

(python:2732): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_realize: assertion `GTK_WIDGET_ANCHORED (widget) || GTK_IS_INVISIBLE (widget)' failed

(python:2732): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_realize: assertion `GTK_WIDGET_ANCHORED (widget) || GTK_IS_INVISIBLE (widget)' failed

(python:2732): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_realize: assertion `GTK_WIDGET_ANCHORED (widget) || GTK_IS_INVISIBLE (widget)' failed

(python:2732): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_realize: assertion `GTK_WIDGET_ANCHORED (widget) || GTK_IS_INVISIBLE (widget)' failed

(python:2732): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_realize: assertion `GTK_WIDGET_ANCHORED (widget) || GTK_IS_INVISIBLE (widget)' failed

(python:2732): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_realize: assertion `GTK_WIDGET_ANCHORED (widget) || GTK_IS_INVISIBLE (widget)' failed

(python:2732): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_realize: assertion `GTK_WIDGET_ANCHORED (widget) || GTK_IS_INVISIBLE (widget)' failed

(python:2732): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_container_add: assertion `GTK_IS_CONTAINER (container)' failed

(python:2732): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_realize: assertion `GTK_WIDGET_ANCHORED (widget) || GTK_IS_INVISIBLE (widget)' failed

(python:2732): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_realize: assertion `GTK_WIDGET_ANCHORED (widget) || GTK_IS_INVISIBLE (widget)' failed

(python:2732): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_container_add: assertion `GTK_IS_CONTAINER (container)' failed

(python:2732): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_realize: assertion `GTK_WIDGET_ANCHORED (widget) || GTK_IS_INVISIBLE (widget)' failed

(python:2732): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_realize: assertion `GTK_WIDGET_ANCHORED (widget) || GTK_IS_INVISIBLE (widget)' failed
Violación de segmento (`core' generado)
```

I assume this has something to do with my linux setup. Anyone faced this before?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The GTK errors are probably unrelated to the segfault. I'm using KDE (and therefore not the gtk theme), so I don't see any GTK errors, but i do get a segfault.

The segfault happens in the destructor of the `QGraphicsScene`:

```
#0  0x00007ffff6f09037 in raise () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007ffff6f0c698 in abort () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#2  0x00007ffff5b465c2 in qt_message_output(QtMsgType, char const*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4
#3  0x00007ffff5b46938 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4
#4  0x00007ffff5b46ac4 in qFatal(char const*, ...) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4
#5  0x00007ffff389231e in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4
#6  0x00007ffff3893401 in QPixmap::QPixmap() () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4
#7  0x00007fffea0a8c86 in Oxygen::Helper::Helper(QByteArray const&) () from /usr/lib/liboxygenstyle.so.4
#8  0x00007fffea3450e0 in ?? () from /usr/lib/kde4/plugins/styles/oxygen.so
#9  0x00007fffea32f757 in ?? () from /usr/lib/kde4/plugins/styles/oxygen.so
#10 0x00007fffea33c7bc in ?? () from /usr/lib/kde4/plugins/styles/oxygen.so
#11 0x00007ffff3ab64e6 in QStyleFactory::create(QString const&) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4
#12 0x00007ffff37c74cf in QApplication::style() () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4
#13 0x00007ffff37fe488 in QWidget::isActiveWindow() const () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4
#14 0x00007ffff3dd5ccc in QGraphicsView::setScene(QGraphicsScene*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4
#15 0x00007ffff3da47d1 in QGraphicsScene::~QGraphicsScene() () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4
#16 0x00007ffff46b6bb9 in ?? () from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyQt4/QtGui.so
#17 0x00007ffff46b4ad6 in ?? () from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyQt4/QtGui.so
#18 0x00007ffff4c6115e in ?? () from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sip.so
#19 0x00007ffff4c62aa9 in ?? () from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sip.so
#20 0x00000000004af4f0 in ?? ()
#21 0x00000000004dbbc7 in ?? ()
#22 0x00007ffff4c6058b in ?? () from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sip.so
#23 0x00007ffff4c62a22 in ?? () from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sip.so
#24 0x00007ffff4c62ab1 in ?? () from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sip.so
#25 0x00000000004af4f0 in ?? ()
#26 0x00000000004b8bca in ?? ()
#27 0x00000000004a4460 in PyDict_SetItem ()
#28 0x00000000004a46d7 in _PyModule_Clear ()
#29 0x0000000000509514 in PyImport_Cleanup ()
#30 0x0000000000423bca in Py_Finalize ()
#31 0x0000000000424470 in Py_Exit ()
#32 0x00000000004245ac in ?? ()
#33 0x000000000042254e in PyErr_PrintEx ()
#34 0x0000000000465e0d in PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags ()
#35 0x0000000000466b78 in Py_Main ()
#36 0x00007ffff6ef3ea5 in __libc_start_main () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#37 0x00000000004e0d95 in _start ()
```

Making `grview` the parent of `scene` should fix this problem:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

grview = QGraphicsView()
scene = QGraphicsScene(grview)

grview.setScene(scene)

grview.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

`QObject`s constructed without parent are [owned by PyQt and not by Qt](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qobject.html#QObject), this error is probably a result of the destructor being called twice when exiting.

Comment: It worked. But I don't understand why it was failing. Why is the setScene call not enough? Anyway, good answer. I am accepting it and closing the question. Thanks!

Comment: I can only speculate that the destructor is called on the Qt side when the QGraphicsView is destroyed, and that it is also called by PyQt when `scene` is [garbage collected](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/gotchas.html#garbage-collection) - but I can't really say which happens first.

Comment: The last sentence should probably read "QObject constructed _with_ parent are owned by Qt instead of PyQt", since the [doc](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qobject.html#QObject) states "The parent argument, if _not_ None, causes self to be owned by Qt instead of PyQt" ?

Comment: The edited version is now fine, and equivalent to that of the documentation, thanks.

Comment: @mata [It does work in pyqt4, but not pyqt5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39107846/segmentation-fault-on-exit-in-pyqt5-but-not-pyqt4).