# Segmentation fault on exit in pyQt5 but not pyQt4

Tags: crash, segmentation-fault, pyqt, pyqt4, pyqt5

The workaround to a crash upon exit given in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18416818/3565696) works in pyqt4.

But not using pyqt5, where there is often (more than half the times) a segmentation fault.

Only the import lines changed

```py
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys

#toolkit = "Qt4"
toolkit = "Qt5"
if toolkit == "Qt4":
  # Qt4 (no crash)
  from PyQt4.QtCore import *
  from PyQt4.QtGui import *
elif toolkit == "Qt5":
  # Qt5 (crash)
  from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication, QGraphicsScene, QGraphicsView
  )


app = QApplication(sys.argv)

grview = QGraphicsView()

# no crash
scene = QGraphicsScene(parent=grview)

grview.setScene(scene)

grview.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Here is the backtrace, [from the core dump](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/wiki/How-to-debug-PyQt-PySide-internal-crashes-(segfaults)-affecting-Spyder) (as a side note, inside gdb, there is no crash)

```
[New LWP 4684]
[New LWP 4683]
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib64/libthread_db.so.1".
Core was generated by `python grview_qt5.py'.
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x00007f5233393e69 in ?? ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007f5233393e69 in  ()
#1  0x00007f522fee6f20 in  ()
#2  0x0000000000e0d340 in  ()
#3  0x00007f522fee6f20 in  ()
#4  0x0000000000e0d5f0 in  ()
#5  0x00007f523e0bc000 in _rtld_local () at /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
#6  0x00007f523ae7285f in QThreadPrivate::start(void*) (arg=0xe0d340) at thread/qthread_unix.cpp:337
#7  0x00007f523d8780a4 in start_thread (arg=0x7f522fee7700) at pthread_create.c:309
#8  0x00007f523d5adcbd in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:111
(gdb) info threads
  Id   Target Id         Frame 
  2    Thread 0x7f523e06f700 (LWP 4683) 0x00007f523deb21c7 in munmap () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:81
* 1    Thread 0x7f522fee7700 (LWP 4684) 0x00007f5233393e69 in ?? ()
```

Why the difference between pyqt4 and pyqt5 ?

It is surely related to [Object Destruction on Exit](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/pyqt4_differences.html#object-destruction-on-exit), but how ?

What is the correct way to avoid this crash ?

Comment: python3 deletes objects at a different time then python2 does. Try use explicit del on the objects before you sys.exit: del grview;del scene;del app;.

Comment: Replace all the graphics stuff with `QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(1000, app.quit)`, so that only a `QApplication` is created. If that still crashes, try with `QCoreApplication` instead. This may help narrow down what the source of the problem is.

Comment: @ekhumoro With all the graphics stuff replaced with `QTimer.singleShot(1000, app.quit)`, there is no crash.

Answer (score 3):

I cannot make your example crash using Fedora 24's PyQt.

However I am also seeing this problem and do not have a definitive answer on how to clean up Qt objects before python exits. My app has 1000's of Qt objects and I'm not at all clear on hopw I will track down all the objects that fail to clean up.

I think the key is that you have to delete all the objects you have created in the reverse order of construction. Taking care to remove objects from any Qt object that has a reference to an other object. e.g widgets in a layout.

As I said in the comment the difference comes from changes from python2 to python3 to do with object deletion and garbage collection.

Using sys.exit() to avoid the clean up is not good enough.

You need to use os._exit( code ) which will prevent python from running onExit handlers. That is more likely to suppress the seg fault. But you will need to make sure that any important onExit handlers are run. For example to delete temp files.

Try exiting like this and see if for you the problem goes away.

```
grview.show()
rc = app.exec_()

del grview
del scene
del app

sys.exit( rc )
```

Comment: In both cases I used the same python version (Python 2.7.12), so how would the difference be explained by "changes from python2 to python3" ?

Comment: The Qt versions are 4.8.6 and 5.4.2

Comment: With your suggestion, no crash. Swapping the del scene and del grview lines there is no crash either. Deleting app, scene and grview in that order, no crash either. Actually the `del grview` and `del scene` are not necessary to prevent the crash. Only the `del app` matters. Why ?

Comment: @ederag. The only real issue here is the order in which objects are deleted by pyqt/python. Using `del` can change the order, and it may even be possible to do it by renaming variables. Essentially, pyqt/python is iterating over a dict when deleting objects, and the order of dict entries is strictly *undefined*. The difference between pyqt4 and pyqt5 is that, by default,  the former automatically calls the C++ destructor of any object it owns on exit, but the latter doesn't. So you could also try adding `import sip; sip.setdestroyonexit(True)` for pyqt5 to see if it makes any difference.

Comment: @ekhumoro Thanks for the "dict" explanation. But the order of deletion does not seem to matter, on the contrary. See my previous comment. With `sip.setdestroyonexit(True)`, it crashes often too.

Comment: @ederag. The order most certainly *does* matter. If it didn't, using `del` would have no affect at all. With PyQt, there are always two sides of an object that need to be deleted: a Python part and a C++ part, each with its own refcount. Using `del` may immediately delete the Python part, but there's no guarantee that the C++ part will be deleted at the same time. It's the *overall* order of deletion that matters when the program exits, and you cannot *directly* control that purely by using `del`.

Comment: @ekhumoro With only `del app` there is no crash. Are you sure the order of deletion matters ? To me it looks like the only important thing is that app is deleted before the call to exit. In this way it is `app` that starts the deletion of Qt objects ? Or am I missing something ?

Comment: @ederag. Please read my previous comment more carefully. Yes, the **overall** order of deletion is the only thing that can possibly matter. This is a well-known problem that has existed for many years in PyQt/PySide, and appears regularly in questions on SO. It is an inherent feature of python garbage-collection that the order of deletion is unpredictable. The issue is that both Python and Qt are trying to delete objects *independently of each other*. This means that it is sometimes possible that Qt tries to delete an object that has already been deleted by Python, which results in a crash.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121788/discussion-between-ederag-and-ekhumoro).

Comment: @ederag when you del a PyQt object it may, or may not, delete objects you have added to it. Also, I suspect, that not all orphaned objects when cleaned up on exit cause a crash. The author of PyQt has not offered advice on this problem, which leaves me making educated guesses.

Comment: @BarryScott Yes, this is uncomfortable. To be investigated again if I manage to get more debugging info. While your post was definitely interesting (thanks, got my +1 already), I still wait for an answer to "how to do this correctly" (meaning in a reliable way). Although the chat discussion left little hope for that.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and just replacing sys.exit(wizard.exec_()) with os.*exit(wizard.exec*()) solved it for me.

Comment: Beware that [`os._exit`](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/os.html?highlight=os%20exit#os._exit) is more brutal than `sys.exit` though (see the linked doc).