# Insert VTK into the right spot of layout

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, vtk, qt-designer

I am trying to put the VTK 3D scene widget into the right spot of pyqtgraphics.GraphicsLayout(). But either the scene does not appear if i am not assigning the window as parent or if I do - the scene does not adapt to the free area, it is just floating in the upper left corner.

I am currently struggling to find a solution to put a viewbox and vtkrenderer into the same window.

One of my attempts was to assign the self.w (see below this paragraph)- which is my main window as a parent to the renderer but then I don't know how to tell the renderer to place itself in the lower right corner of the window instead of floating in the upper left corner - which also leads to overlapping of other elements in the window.

Creating new window and assigning this window as parent

```
self.vtkWidget = QVTKRenderWindowInteractor(self.w_3d)
```

Using refered window as parent -> leads to floating and overlapping rendered scene

```
self.vtkWidget = QVTKRenderWindowInteractor(self.w)
```

[image]

```
import pyqtgraph as pg
import pyqtgraph.opengl as gl
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import Qt
from vtk.qt.QVTKRenderWindowInteractor import QVTKRenderWindowInteractor
import vtk, sys

class GUI:
    def __init__(self):
        self.init_gui() 

    def proxyWidget(self, item, width=None, height=None):
        proxy = QtGui.QGraphicsProxyWidget()
        if(height != None):
            height = item.sizeHint().height() if height==None else height
            item.setMaximumHeight(height)
        if(width!=None):
            width = item.sizeHint().width() if width==None else width
            item.setMaximumWidth(width)
        proxy.setWidget(item)
        return proxy

    def init_gui(self, win_height=800, win_width=1800):
        #self.w = self
        #self.w.scene().sigMouseClicked.connect(self.mousePressEvent) #mouseMoveEvent
        #self.w.scene().sigMouseMoved.connect(self.mouseMoveEvent)
        pg.setConfigOptions(imageAxisOrder='row-major')
        pg.setConfigOption('background', 'w')
        pg.setConfigOption('foreground', 'k')
        self.w = pg.GraphicsWindow(size=(win_width,win_height), border=True)
        self.img = pg.ImageItem()
        self.list_imgs       = QtGui.QListWidget()
        self.btn_Del_Mark    = QtGui.QPushButton('Del Mark')
        self.btn_MarkPed     = QtGui.QPushButton('Mark ped')
        self.lbl_list1       = QtGui.QLabel("List Images")
        self.lbl_list2       = QtGui.QLabel("List Markings")
        self.list_imgs       = QtGui.QListWidget()
        self.list_marks      = QtGui.QListWidget()
        self.layout = pg.GraphicsLayout()
        self.w_3d = pg.GraphicsWindow()
        self.vb = pg.ViewBox()


        self.lbl_list1.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.lbl_list2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.vb.setAspectLocked()
        self.vb.addItem(self.img)
        self.vb.invertY(True)
        self.vtkWidget = QVTKRenderWindowInteractor(self.w_3d)
        self.w_3d.addItem(self.proxyWidget(self.vtkWidget))

        self.vtkWidget.Initialize()
        self.vtkWidget.Start()
        self.ren = vtk.vtkRenderer()
        self.vtkWidget.GetRenderWindow().AddRenderer(self.ren)
        self.iren = self.vtkWidget.GetRenderWindow().GetInteractor()

        # Create source
        source = vtk.vtkSphereSource()
        source.SetCenter(0, 0, 0)
        source.SetRadius(5.0)

        # Create a mapper
        mapper = vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper()
        mapper.SetInputConnection(source.GetOutputPort())

        # Create an actor
        actor = vtk.vtkActor()
        actor.SetMapper(mapper)

        self.ren.AddActor(actor)

        self.ren.ResetCamera()
        self.iren.Initialize()
        self.iren.Start()
        self.vtkWidget.show()

        self.layout.addItem(self.vb                             , 1,  3, 20,  20)
        self.layout.addItem(self.proxyWidget(self.lbl_list1     , width=(int(1./10.*win_width)), height=(int(0.9/20.*win_height))),  0,1,1,1)   
        self.layout.addItem(self.proxyWidget(self.lbl_list2     , width=(int(1./10.*win_width)), height=(int(0.9/20.*win_height))),  0,2,1,1)  
        self.layout.addItem(self.proxyWidget(self.list_imgs     , width=(int(1./10.*win_width))),  1,1,20,1)   
        self.layout.addItem(self.proxyWidget(self.list_marks    , width=(int(1./10.*win_width))),  1,2,20,1)   

        self.w.addItem(self.layout)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication([])
    guiobj = GUI()

    if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
        QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```

**EDIT:**

Currently I have solved it by having two windows - after several days of failed attempts. But even this looks crap - since the rendered scene floats in the window without reaction to window resize events...

[image]

I would like to have those two windows - in one:

[image]

One of the failed attempts was as follows - but then pyqt acquires space in the layout without showing the renderer scene in the window... - just empty space:

```
self.vtkWidget = QVTKRenderWindowInteractor() #No Parent
#...see rest of code in the section above with exception of the following 2 lines
self.layout.addItem(self.proxyWidget(self.vtkWidget), 10, 3, 10, 20)
self.vtkWidget.show()
```

Comment: Okay maybe its just me but it appears as if you have a sort of circular reference going on here -- vtkWidget is dependent upon w-3d which is dependent upon layout_3d which is dependent upon vtkWidget ??  Which could be part of the problem of why its not working as expected.  So which comes first the chicken or the egg?

Comment: @DennisJensen yes but  - in this example they are two seperate windows - but the issue is - i can not handout layout_3d as parent - since it does not accept an object of the class graphicslayout - so i do not know how to work around this issue...

Comment: @DennisJensen i would like anyway to have all widgets in a single window.. :/

Comment: I am sure there is a way to do it but I do not have time to look at it right at this minute.  Still you need to reword your question I think -- at least outlining in a bit more detail what your issue fully is -- because I do not think that circular reference is ever going to work correctly if at all

Comment: @DennisJensen ok i will do it now - because i have been working on it for several days - and i still have no clue - why is not working ...

if i am inserting the widget directly into the layout by layout.addItem(...) 
and without bypassing a parent to the vtkwidget - it does not appear at all in the window

Comment: @DennisJensen  i have edited the description

Comment: okay I installed pyqtgraph and tried to run what is supposed to be a Minimal Reproducible Example and get the following `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "zzTest06.py", line 5, in <module>
    import pyqtgraph.opengl as gl
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\pyqtgraph\opengl\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .GLViewWidget import GLViewWidget
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\pyqtgraph\opengl\GLViewWidget.py", line 2, in <module>
    from OpenGL.GL import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'OpenGL'`

Comment: Further that would not be the only error I would get because you reference within this code `QVTKRenderWindowInteractor` which was not imported.  If you actually post an MRE let me know and I will take another look.

Comment: @DennisJensen thnx for your ongoing effort - i have edited the code - see above thanks in advance

Comment: @DennisJensen thank you for your efforts and good intentions - i was able to solve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve it - I have replaced the QGraphicsLayout with QGridlayout and removed all proxywidget-wrappers and I found a workaround for adding a viewbox by using the plotwidget.

I just need now to remove the axes - but this is secondary

```
import pyqtgraph as pg
import pyqtgraph.opengl as gl
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import Qt
from vtk.qt.QVTKRenderWindowInteractor import QVTKRenderWindowInteractor
import vtk, sys
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
class GUI:
    def __init__(self):
        self.init_gui() 

    def proxyWidget(self, item, width=None, height=None):
        proxy = QtGui.QGraphicsProxyWidget()
        if(height != None):
            height = item.sizeHint().height() if height==None else height
            item.setMaximumHeight(height)
        if(width!=None):
            width = item.sizeHint().width() if width==None else width
            item.setMaximumWidth(width)
        proxy.setWidget(item)
        return proxy

    def init_gui(self, win_height=800, win_width=1800):
        pg.setConfigOptions(imageAxisOrder='row-major')
        pg.setConfigOption('background', 'w')
        pg.setConfigOption('foreground', 'k')
        self.w = pg.GraphicsWindow(size=(win_width,win_height), border=True)
        self.img = pg.ImageItem()
        self.list_imgs       = QtGui.QListWidget()
        self.btn_Del_Mark    = QtGui.QPushButton('Del Mark')
        self.btn_MarkPed     = QtGui.QPushButton('Mark ped')
        self.lbl_list1       = QtGui.QLabel("List Images")
        self.lbl_list2       = QtGui.QLabel("List Markings")
        self.list_imgs       = QtGui.QListWidget()
        self.list_marks      = QtGui.QListWidget()
        self.layout = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        self.w.setLayout(self.layout)
        #self.w_3d = pg.GraphicsWindow()

        self.vtkWidget = QVTKRenderWindowInteractor()
        #self.w_3d.addItem(self.proxyWidget(self.vtkWidget))

        self.vtkWidget.Initialize()
        self.vtkWidget.Start()
        self.ren = vtk.vtkRenderer()
        self.vtkWidget.GetRenderWindow().AddRenderer(self.ren)
        self.iren = self.vtkWidget.GetRenderWindow().GetInteractor()

        # Create source
        source = vtk.vtkSphereSource()
        source.SetCenter(0, 0, 0)
        source.SetRadius(5.0)

        # Create a mapper
        mapper = vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper()
        mapper.SetInputConnection(source.GetOutputPort())

        # Create an actor
        actor = vtk.vtkActor()
        actor.SetMapper(mapper)

        self.ren.AddActor(actor)

        self.ren.ResetCamera()
        self.iren.Initialize()
        self.iren.Start()
        path = "/home/brain/uni/frustum-pointnets/dataset/KITTI/object/testing/image_2/000000.png"
        imgdata = Image.open(path)
        self.imgArr = np.array(imgdata)
        #ToDo: undistort Image if neccessary

        self.img.setImage(self.imgArr)
        #self.vbLayout = self.w.addLayout(row=0,  col=3, rowspan=10,  colspan=20)
        imageGraph = pg.PlotWidget(name='Signalgraph')
        self.vb = imageGraph.plotItem.vb
        self.lbl_list1.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.lbl_list2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.vb.setAspectLocked()
        self.vb.addItem(self.img)
        self.vb.invertY(True)
        self.vb.setMaximumSize(int(7/10.*win_width), int(9/20.*win_height))
        self.layout.addWidget(imageGraph,                           1 , 3, 10,  20)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.vtkWidget                      , 11, 3, 10,  20)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.lbl_list1 ,                                  0, 1, 1, 1)   
        self.layout.addWidget(self.lbl_list2 ,                                  0, 2, 1, 1)  
        self.layout.addWidget(self.list_imgs ,                                  1, 1, 20,1)   
        self.layout.addWidget(self.list_marks,                                  1, 2, 20,1)   
        sizeHint =  lambda: pg.QtCore.QSize(int(1./10.*win_width), int(0.9/20.*win_height))
        self.lbl_list1.sizeHint = lambda: pg.QtCore.QSize(int(1./10.*win_width), int(0.9/20.*win_height))
        self.lbl_list2.sizeHint = lambda: pg.QtCore.QSize(int(1./10.*win_width), int(0.9/20.*win_height))
        self.list_imgs.sizeHint  = lambda: pg.QtCore.QSize(int(1./10.*win_width), int(18/20.*win_height))
        self.list_marks.sizeHint = lambda: pg.QtCore.QSize(int(1./10.*win_width), int(18/20.*win_height))
        self.list_imgs.setMaximumWidth(int(1./10.*win_width))
        self.list_marks.setMaximumWidth(int(1./10.*win_width))

        self.vtkWidget.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication([])
    guiobj = GUI()

    if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
        QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```

Comment: Just a note -- you ought to clean up your Import lines as they are a bit confusing and jumbled.  For instance which Qt library are you actually using as you Import 2 of them under different Namespaces

Comment: @DennisJensen thnx for the hint - I have been starting programming this program and adding and removing things when I came across certain problems, I clearly have to clean the code up..